# Use Adsense Management V2 API with Google API JavaScript client Wa`parent Error

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client, adsense-api

I'm trying to use the [google-api-javascript-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) with the Adsense Management API to get [reports](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reference/rest/v2/accounts.reports.saved/list) of an authorized account. The login process with OAuth2 is working fine and I can fetch the Adsense Account data associated to the logged-in Google Account. (see `generateReportExmaple -> accountList`) However when I try to get reports or work with any other resource (site, reports...) I get the following error:

```json
Uncaught (in promise) pB 
{
  message: "Wa`parent", 
  SL: true, 
  stack: "gapi.client.Error: Wa`parent
    at new pB (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1003:190)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1067:432)
    at Object._.em (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:454:399)
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1067:147
    at Object._.dm (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:454:201)
    at CC (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1067:128)
    at Object.AC (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:1066:48)
    at Object.list (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.de.soliK2B9LKA.O/m=auth2,client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AGLTcCP_VSmeyDlYE1vxFyfmddhL6RM9dw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:176:135)
    at generateReportExmaple (http://localhost:5500/stack.html:64:91)"}
```

I found a [few examples in the github repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/search?q=adsense) of the api-js-client but they are quite oudated. I'm also confused why the `reports` object is attached to the `accounts` object of the gapi client. In all there examples the `reports` are in the `adsense` object. In my case all are attached in `adsense.accounts`.

This is my code:

```html
<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

<script>
  const apiKey = 'API_KEY';
  const discoveryDocs = ["https://adsense.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2"];
  const clientId = 'CLIENT_ID_KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  const scopes = "profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly";
  
  const authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  const signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
  
  function handleClientLoad() {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }
  
  async function initClient() {
      await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: apiKey,
          discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
          clientId: clientId,
          scope: scopes
      })
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
  }
  
  // Here I fetch the data
  async function generateReportExmaple() {
      const accountsList = await gapi.client.adsense.accounts.list() // Result is fine
  
      const savedReports = await gapi.client.adsense.reports.saved.list() // Cannot read property 'saved' of undefined
      
      const savedReportsStrangeError = await gapi.client.adsense.accounts.reports.saved.list() // cb=gapi.loaded_0:1003 Uncaught (in promise) pB {message: "Wa`parent"....
  }
  
  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
      if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          generateReportExmaple()
      } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
  
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }
  
  function handleSignoutClick(event) {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting such an odd error message, but the two issues you're seeing are explainable as:

1. The `reports.saved.list` method only exists in adsense v1.4, and you're using v2, so the `adsense.reports` Javascript object doesn't exist.
2. The `accounts.reports.saved.list` method [has a required `parent` parameter](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reference/rest/v2/accounts.reports.saved/list) that specifies the account that you're accessing the saved reports for. (This is the same value as one of the `accounts[].name` in the result you get from calling `accounts.list`, for example.)

Comment: In the meantime, I raised https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/766 for the inscrutable error message.